# How can I manually override the IIS Directory for an ASP.Net project opened by VS2008 but created on another machine?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have an ASP.Net project created by a team member on another computer. The project references a virtual directory that exists on my computer but under a different localhost location.

Currently, the following error occurs when I try to open the project:

> The local IIS URL `http://localhost/foo/default.aspx` specified for Web project foobar has not been configured. In order to open this project the virtual directory needs to be configured. Would you like to create the virtual directory now?
>   [Yes] [No]

So, there are two options:

1. select yes: It creates the virtual directory that it thinks I need, which I don't want to do. I already have a virtual directory somewhere else.
2. select no: This isn't an option, as the project opens, but without all the bells and whistles I know and love.

Where is the virtual directory location (in my case `http://localhost/foo/default.aspx`) specified within the project? Can I change this manually, say in a configuration file within the project, either before or after I open it? A configuration change seems more ideal than manually opening IIS to override a virtual directory path.

**EDIT (solution)**: Buried in the comments below is the following answer (Thanks @Thyamine)

This can be configured in the foo.csproj file for the project.

Look for the lines:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
        <FlavorProperties GUID="{F00-000-000}">
            <WebProjectProperties>
                <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
                <!-- ... -->
                <IISUrl>http://localhost/Foo/default.aspx</IISUrl> <!-- EDIT THIS LINE -->
                <!-- ... -->
            </WebProjectProperties>
        </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could allow it to create the directory, then re-map it in IIS Manager to point to the directory you would prefer it to use.

Or you could tell it not to map at all, and then manually create the virtual directory with IIS Manager to the directory you already have.

Comment: A valid solution. I'm wondering, though, if it's possible to update in a config file without having to open and fiddle with IIS manually. I've done a half-dozen similar projects, all of which require this type of manual remapping hassle. A minor text/config update would be far more efficient... in theory.

Comment: It would depend how the project is built/distributed.  If it's an executable then you probably don't have a lot of choice.  If the files are all bundled in a folder that just gets copied you may be able to make some adjustments to a file first.

Comment: True. It's a series of files bundled in a folder. Any idea which file I should adjust? :)

Comment: You can always try opening the project or solution files in something like Notepad and see what data is in there.  When I open a solution file I can see a lot of the mappings listed that you would otherwise adjust in the project properties.  Maybe you can edit a setting there first before opening the project.

Comment: That was it! The foo.csproj file contains two tags: UseIIS and IISUrl. By updating IISUrl, I can specify the path of the directory to whatever I need. Thanks for the pointers!